# Problem with Max() function and other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max

Here is my query

```
Select max(sale) as MaximumSales, cID
From(
Select SUM(totalPerSale) as sale,CustomerID as cID
From(
Select Quantity, UnitPrice, 
Quantity*UnitPrice as totalPerSale, CustomerID
From DbAssignment.`e-commerce-2021 (1)` order by totalPerSale DESC
) as Records 
group by CustomerID order by CustomerID DESC)
as total
```

What I am trying to do is get the customer who spent the most money....
the inner subquery with alias Records is working as expected. it is returning sum of amounts spend for each customer. But the outer most query alias as total does not give the correct CustomerID
It returns the first CustomerID in dataset when I use it with the outermost select...MAX is returning correct data though....

How do I solve this...

any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are requesting fields you never use, for one thing, and I'm wondering why you don't just group by the customerID, sort by the product, and then limit to the top 1.

```
SELECT customerID, sum(Quantity*UnitPrice) as sales
FROM DbAssignment.`e-commerce-2021 (1)` 
GROUP BY customerID
ORDER BY sum(Quantity*UnitPrice)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks man.... i dont know why i was so much focusing on my MAX() to work.... My bad....

Comment: no problem, we all get blinders some times.  If this helped you, remember to accept it as the answer.